# How to make cmake support gcov

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, code-coverage, gcov

I'm working with C++ on Ubuntu and trying to `make` two targets with the help of `cmake`, one is the normal exe and the other is to run the unit-test. here is my project:

```
|---include
|     |---Student.h
|
|---src
|    |---Student.cpp
|    |---main.cpp
|
|---unittest
|      |---TestStudent.cpp
|
|---CMakeLists.txt   # how to write this file?
```

Now the `CmakeLists.txt` is like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(Student CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCES src/Student.cpp)
set(INCLUDES include)

find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

add_executable(student src/main.cpp ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(student PRIVATE ${INCLUDES})
target_compile_options(student PRIVATE -std=c++11 -g)

add_executable(student-test unittest/TestStudent.cpp ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(student-test PRIVATE ${INCLUDES})
target_compile_options(student-test PRIVATE -std=c++11 -g -O0)
target_link_libraries(student-test -lgtest -lpthread -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage)

enable_testing()
include(GoogleTest)
gtest_add_tests(TARGET student-test AUTO)
```

So, after executing `mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make`, two executable files are generated: `student` and `student-test`. However, when I execute `./student-test`, the raw coverage file isn't generated. But if I compile it with the pure command: `g++ -std=c++11 TestStudent.cpp ../src/Student.cpp -I ../include/ -lgtest -lpthread -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -g -O0 -o student-test`, it works without any problem, meaning that `./student-test` could generate the relative raw coverage files.

Why can't the `CmakeLists.txt` do the same thing?

Comment: Why is `-ftest-coverage` in `target_link_libraries` (and not a compiler flag)? I believe `-coverage` needs to be added to `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`. The compiler will do the right thing if it drives link.

Comment: @jww   So do you mean I need to add `-coverage` into `target_compile_options(student-test PRIVATE -std=c++11 -g -O0 -coverage)`? I've tried but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Moia  Sorry, I still don't know what I could do.